# Run shell script on boot / start

Tags: android, service, init, boot, scriptmanager

First of all , my rooted phone is Xiao Mi Red Mi Note 7.

MIUI version : 10.2.3.

Android Version : 9 PKQ1.180904.001.

**Shell script :**

```
set -xeo pipefail

_stopnow() {
  test -f stopnow && echo "Stopping!" && rm stopnow && exit 0 || return 0
}

while true

do

    _stopnow

    am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.package.mobile.name com.package.mobile.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

done
```

**What i have tried :**

1. Use [SManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager) Version : 3.0.9

[image]

Conclusion of this method : Killed

2. Use **service.rc in /system/etc/init**

Because i did not have /init.d folder i am using /init instead.

I have file named */system/etc/init/mypackagepipefail.rc* and */system/bin/runpipefail*

**mypackagepipefail.rc**

```
on boot
    start /system/bin/runpipefail
    user system
    group system readproc
```

**runpipefail**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -xeo pipefail

_stopnow() {
  test -f stopnow && echo "Stopping!" && rm stopnow && exit 0 || return 0
}

while true
do
    _stopnow
    # Below here, you put in your command you want to run:
    am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.airasia.mobile.BigpayTest com.airasia.mobile.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Conclusion of this method : seems like service does not running on start / boot.

Is there something wrong in usage of the service.rc above ?
Is there any other method to run shell script on boot ?

Any help would be so great.
Thank you very much.

Comment: See if your root method provides su.d like support.

Comment: what can i do to checking if root provides it ?

Comment: Look for /su.d folder

Comment: what if there is not /su.d folder ? i did not found /su.d on my phone

Comment: then i can only suggest to update to magisk as it provides su.d support and much more